# How to pass data from API with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, react-props

I'm currently implementing a feature in a table that has data. On this table you can perform an action to the specific entry. Upon that an icon will appear next to the name with the action that has been requested that is currently waiting for approval. I'm having an issue trying to have real data from the API instead of hard corded information inside of the modal.

I currently have a component named `StatusModal` that has the hard coded information. I plan on reusing this component in other tables I do not want the data from my API in here.

```
       const details = {
            ActionRequested: "Canceled",
            RequestedBy: "Jon Snow",
            ActionStatus: "Pending",
        }

    return (
        <div>
            <WarningIcon
                className={classes.warningIcon}
                aria-describedby={id}
                variant="contained"
                onClick={handleClick}>
                Open Popover
            </WarningIcon>
            <Popover
                id={id}
                open={open}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                onClose={handleClose}
                anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "center"
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: "top",
                    horizontal: "center"
                }}>
                <Typography className={classes.typography} variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom >
                      Action Requested: {details.ActionRequested}   </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.typography} variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom>
                     Requested By: {details.RequestedBy}
                </Typography> 
              <Typography  className={classes.typography} variant="subtitle1"  gutterBottom>
                    Action Status: {details.ActionStatus}
                </Typography>
            </Popover>
        </div>
```

Second, I have another component named `StaffTable` which has the data from my API. I am trying to get the values of ActionRequested and RequestedBy from my API into the imported StatusModal. I am trying to have an object with the 2 values that I am trying to receive with  **StatusModal details={ { ActionType,RequestedByName }**

```
function StaffTable({ staff, showAlert, refresh, classes }) {
    const [sortType, setSortType] = useState(null);

    const [updatedStaff, setUpdatedStaff] = useState(staff);
    // console.log(staff);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setUpdatedStaff(staff);
    }, [staff]);

    const initialColumns = [

{
            name: "",
            label: "",
            options: {
                filter: false,
                sort: false,
                customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => {
                        console.log(tableMeta, "tableMeta")
                    return (
                        <StatusModal
                        details={() => {
                            const { ActionType, RequestedByName } = updatedStatus[
                                tableMeta.rowIndex
                            ];

                            showModal({
                                metadata: {
                                    ActionType: ActionType,
                                    RequestedByName: RequestedByName
                                },
                            });
                        }}>
                        {value}
                    </StatusModal>
                        )
                }
            }
        },
```

I am currently not getting back any data back which then I am unable to pass into my `StatusModal` what is the best way of approaching what I'm trying to achieve?